# Silverman Hensel's Lemma for Selmer and Sha

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, hensels-lemma

I am reading Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. In Section X.4 (The Selmer and Shafarevich-Tate Groups) Silverman derives a diagram relating the cohomology of the elliptic curve E over the absolute galois group $G(\overline{K}/K)$ to its cohomology over $G_\nu \simeq G(\overline{K_\nu}/K_\nu)$. If it's helpful the diagram is on the top of page 332 in my second edition book, but my question is just that to compute one part:
$$ \ker\left( H^1(G_\nu, E[\varphi]) \rightarrow WC(E/K_\nu)[\varphi] \right)$$
Silverman says "the question of whether a curve has a point over a complete local field $K_\nu$ reduces by Hensel's lemma to checking whether the curve has a point in some finite ring $R_\nu / M_\nu^e$ for some easily computable integer $e$."

My question is why do we need to consider $R_\nu / M_\nu^e$ rather than $R_\nu / M_\nu$? Shouldn't solutions exist over $R_\nu / M_\nu^e$ if and only if they exist over $R_\nu / M_\nu$?

Comment: Ah right, thank you! 
For future reference for myself: If the derivative of your polynomial happens to be identically zero due to the characteristic you need to use a version of Hensel's such as theorem 4.1 here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf. You can check that for that theorem a solution mod 4 isn't strong enough to get the required strict inequality which is why we go mod 8. 
I'm guessing this would also be an issue for polynomials like x^3 = a if p = 3 and so on?

Comment: @reuns your statement about odd $p$ is only enough if you're determining if something is a square. If say you were e.g., figuring out local solutions to Selmer's cubic then working mod $3$ would not be enough from $3$-adic solutions

Comment: Ok Silverman certainly meant "given any polynomial equation we can compute $e$ such that it suffices to solve it in $O_K/(\pi^e)$ then extend to $O_K$ with Hensel lemma, up to a few special cases like $y^2=x^3+x$ with $v(x)$ large which needs a special treatment similar to $v(x)$ negative"

Comment: Could you elaborate on what goes wrong with $y^2 = x^3 + x$ and $\nu(x)$ large or negative?